# Как можно оптимизировать многопоточный скрипт на python, работающий по большому списку?

Tags: python, оптимизация

```
num_threads = 40 # число макс потоков в пуле

def get_article(proxies, links): # функция получения содержимого страницы
    i, link = links #распаковываем кортеж links
    try:
        proxy = proxies.popleft() #берем прокси
        domain = re.findall('://(.+?)/', link) #вытаскиваем домен из урла
        domain = domain[0] #вытаскиваем домен
        response = requests.get(link, timeout = 30, proxies={"https": proxy}) # открываем страницу
        doc = Document(response.text)
        h = HTML2Text()
        h.ignore_links = True
        h.ignore_images = True
        title = doc.title()
        article = h.handle(doc.summary())
        content = title+"\n\n"+article
        print(content)
    except Exception as e:
        print('Ошибка:', link, proxy, traceback.format_exc())
    finally:
        proxies.append(proxy)
proxies = load_proxies()



all_links = enumerate(all_links) # нумерованный список со ссылками, длина порядка 200 тысяч строк и выше, строки вида http://domain.ru/lalal/allaa.html


with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_threads) as pool:
    pool.map(lambda sitemap: get_article(proxies, sitemap), all_links)
```

Подскажите пожалуйста по моему коду многопоточного парсинга контента со страниц. При запуске дико жрет ресурсы-как я понимаю причина в том, что подается большой массив данных, на маленьких такого не наблюдалось. Как можно оптимизировать его? Пока вижу только вариант разбивать входной список на несколько поменьше и подавать их по очереди. Может есть более красивый способ?

Comment: А кто такие `Document` и `HTML2Text`? Не нужно ли их случайно создавать через `with`? Или может достаточно одну копию создать и с ней работать? Но тогда придётся как-то бороться с `GIL`. Вы для начала разберитесь - что и сколько ест времени и ресурсов, тогда можно будет соображать, где это всё ускорять. Может долго именно сайты скачиваются, тогда сайты качать многопоточно, а дальнейшую обработку в один поток делать, например. Смотреть нужно конкретику.

Comment: Когда потоков больше чем ядер и они их интенсивно используют, то очень много времени уходит в пустую на постоянное переключение контекстов. Но с вашим кодом невозможно определить сколько потоков действительно используют процессор, а сколько ожидают получения данных по сети. Кроме того не надо забывать про GIL, HTML2Text его отпускает на время парсинга или нет ? Если нет, то возможно потребуется разделение на процессы, а не потоки

Comment: @Mike Только вот процессы ещё больше памяти съедят сразу. И ресурсов на переключение )  Но попробовать то можно

Comment: Document и html2text это библиотеки: 
import html2text
from readability import Document

Comment: @CrazyElf Памяти - да. А время переключения не зависит от того процесс это или поток. Да и не надо их запускать больше чем ядер. Сам запуск процесса конечно дольше идет. Значит их надо запустить один раз по количеству ядер, а дальше раздавать им работу.

Comment: @bobr Так какие именно ресурсы сильно загружены и как именно. Все ядра процессора сильно загружены или может только одно ядро под 100%. Или вы про какие то другие ресурсы говорили ?

Comment: @Mike Ну вообще-то при создании нового процесса туда ещё нужно передать копию всех данных порождающего процесса, сериализация и всё такое. Так что как минимум создание процесса - это более тяжелоёмкое дело, чем создание потока.

Comment: @CrazyElf Ну это все равно гораздо лучше, чем когда все потоки одного процесса спят на GIL